Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError
I using firestore for study functions so when i went run that aplication appear this error, if this important, i use npx
"Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error"
Error:
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
^^^^^^
Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error
Code:
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import {onDocumentWritten} from "firebase-functions/lib/v2/providers/firestore";
export function nameUser = onDocumentWritten("/users/{userId}", (event) => {
functions.logger.info(ID >> ${event.data?.after.data()}, {structuredData: true});
})

I suggest taking a moment to learn how to format your text and code so it's more readable on Stack Overflow.  You can edit your question with improvements using the edit link at the bottom.

Hi, read formatting help
